# Return a finite set matching a regex expression

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

Something similar to http://regexio.com/prototype.html, I'm trying to get a set matching a particular regex.

Comment: Any set will do? I am guessing you need this for test case generation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to parse the regular expression and then, instead of *reading* input while walking the parsed expression, *output* the variants.

I have hacked the following program doing what you need for a *very* simple regular expression (only alternate options using `|`, iteration using `*`, grouping using `()`, and escaping using `\` is supported). Note that the iteration is done simply 0–5 times, conversion to possibly infinite iteration left as an exercise for the reader ;-).

I have used a straightforward recursive-descent parser building an abstract syntax tree in memory; this tree is in the end walked and all possible sets are built. The solution is probably not optimal at all, but it works. Enjoy:

```
public class TestPrg
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var expression = new RegexParser("a(b|c)*d").Parse();

        foreach (var item in expression.Generate())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Build a Cartesian product of a sequence of sequences
    // Code by Eric Lippert, copied from <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }
}

public class RegexParser
{
    private const char EOF = '\x0000';
    private readonly string str;
    private char curr;
    private int pos;

    public RegexParser(string s)
    {
        str = s;
    }

    public RegExpression Parse()
    {
        pos = -1;
        Read();
        return ParseExpression();
    }

    private void Read()
    {
        ++pos;
        curr = pos < str.Length ? str[pos] : EOF;
    }

    private RegExpression ParseExpression()
    {
        var term = ParseTerm();
        if (curr == '|')
        {
            Read();
            var secondExpr = ParseExpression();
            return new Variants(term, secondExpr);
        }
        else
        {
            return term;
        }
    }

    private RegExpression ParseTerm()
    {
        var factor = ParseFactor();
        if (curr != '|' && curr != '+' && curr != '*' && curr != ')' && curr != EOF)
        {
            var secondTerm = ParseTerm();
            return new Concatenation(factor, secondTerm);
        }
        else
        {
            return factor;
        }
    }

    private RegExpression ParseFactor()
    {
        var element = ParseElement();
        if (curr == '*')
        {
            Read();
            return new Repeat(element);
        }
        else
        {
            return element;
        }
    }

    private RegExpression ParseElement()
    {
        switch (curr)
        {
            case '(':
                Read();
                var expr = ParseExpression();
                if (curr != ')') throw new FormatException("Closing paren expected");
                Read();
                return expr;

            case '\\':
                Read();
                var escapedChar = curr;
                Read();
                return new Literal(escapedChar);

            default:
                var literal = curr;
                Read();
                return new Literal(literal);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class RegExpression
{
    protected static IEnumerable<RegExpression> Merge<T>(RegExpression head, RegExpression tail, Func<T, IEnumerable<RegExpression>> selector)
        where T : RegExpression
    {
        var other = tail as T;
        if (other != null)
        {
            return new[] { head }.Concat(selector(other));
        }
        else
        {
            return new[] { head, tail };
        }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<string> Generate();
}

public class Variants : RegExpression
{
    public IEnumerable<RegExpression> Subexpressions { get; private set; }

    public Variants(RegExpression term, RegExpression rest)
    {
        Subexpressions = Merge<Variants>(term, rest, c => c.Subexpressions);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Generate()
    {
        return Subexpressions.SelectMany(sub => sub.Generate());
    }
}

public class Concatenation : RegExpression
{
    public IEnumerable<RegExpression> Subexpressions { get; private set; }

    public Concatenation(RegExpression factor, RegExpression rest)
    {
        Subexpressions = Merge<Concatenation>(factor, rest, c => c.Subexpressions);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Generate()
    {
        foreach (var variant in Subexpressions.Select(sub => sub.Generate()).CartesianProduct())
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in variant) builder.Append(item);
            yield return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class Repeat : RegExpression
{
    public RegExpression Expr { get; private set; }

    public Repeat(RegExpression expr)
    {
        Expr = expr;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Generate()
    {
        foreach (var subexpr in Expr.Generate())
        {
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; ++cnt)
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder(subexpr.Length * cnt);
                for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) builder.Append(subexpr);
                yield return builder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Literal : RegExpression
{
    public char Ch { get; private set; }

    public Literal(char c)
    {
        Ch = c;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Generate()
    {
        yield return new string(Ch, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534862/generate-all-permutations-of-text-from-a-regex-pattern-in-c/1534953#1534953) might work for you.  If the regex doesn't involve
any * operations (so that the language it recognizes is finite), it should be easy
to rewrite the regex as a BNF grammar, then do a bottom-up analysis producing
the finite sets corresponding to each nonterminal symbol until you reach the
start symbol, at which point you're done.